# String format empty string caused extra space in print

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to string format a sentence as below:

```
integer = 1
if integer != 1:
    n_val, book = integer, 'books'
else:
    n_val, book ='', 'book'

print(f'Fetch the top {n_val} children {book}.')
```

and I expected to see:

```
Fetch the top 3 children books.
```

or

```
Fetch the top children book.
```

It works if integer is not 1, however, when `integer =1`, the string format gives me an additional space in the place of integer as shown below:

```
Fetch the top  children book.
```

How do I get rid of the space when `integer =1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the space part of the variable.

```
integer = 1
if integer != 1:
    n_val, book = ' '+str(integer), 'books'
else:
    n_val, book ='', 'book'

print(f'Fetch the top{n_val} children {book}.')
```

Comment: suggestion: `n_val, book = f" {integer}", 'books'`

Comment: That's a smart solution, thank you:)

Comment: For this cases it is common to set the plural like this: `plural = '' if integer == 1 else 's'` `print(f'Fetch the top{n_val} children book{plural}.')`